# What is the connection between the word 'Stay' and 'Guy' in a crossword?

Tags: synonyms

The clue is 'Remain; guy (4)' and the answer is apparently "Stay".

I can understand remain/stay. But I can't find anything in the dictionary that connects it to the word Guy. The closest I could think of is perhaps guy-ropes being used to keep something fixed in place, but it's tenuous at best and I wouldn't use the word 'guy' on its own in such a manner.

Is the word 'Guy' synonymous in some way with the word 'Stay'?

Comment: A 'guy rope' or just [**guy**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/guy) is a [**stay³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stay) (support) for a tent. *A device used as a brace or support.* The clue is a word play between different noun and verb meanings of **stay**.

Comment: @WeatherVane - More familiar to someone who works with sailboats.

Comment: I see, thanks. Have never heard 'stay' as a noun meaning a support, nor 'guy' without rope as a suffix in that context.

Comment: @NibblyPig in my grandmother's grandmother's day, some women wore 'stays' to support portions of their anatomy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Which helped attract the guys.